# Ngrok Connection Issue X509 error Reconnecting

Tags: visual-studio, botframework, ngrok, terminal-emulator

While Launching Ngrok in cmd prompt, i am getting this.. Is there any solution. I think it is something related to SSL Certificate.
***reconnecting (x509: certificate signed by unknown authority)***
Please do help.[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olXl.png)

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure ngrok to redirect to `http://localhost:3978` that is, the **http** endpoint (**not the https**)

Comment: Thanks @Miguel , i tried to redirect it here also, but doesn't work same error.

Comment: ngrok http 3978 -host-header="localhost:3978"

Comment: Suggestion: include the images directly in your question, just paste it from the clipboard. Are you using Fiddler or something similar? or are you behind a corporate firewall that "inspects" https traffic?

Comment: Behind Corporate Firewall

Comment: Well, in that case you should probably talk to IT to have them add that certificate as a trusted one in your computer or, better yet, install the certificate for internal CA that signs that certificate.